# Create a tree view of layer groups and sub layers using ArcGIS JavaScript API

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, table-of-contents

I'm trying to create a tree view of layer groups and sub layers, I searched Google, and I found something called the Table Of Contents widget. I couldn't use it, or in other words, I don't know how to use it. I tried but didn't work for me.

Can anyone help me in this problem?
I'm trying to use this widget http://gmaps-utility-gis.googlecode.com/svn/tags/agsjs/latest/examples/toc.html.

This is my code:

```
     <html>
 <head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
<title>Task</title>
<link href="tabcontent.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://js.arcgis.com/3.11/dijit/themes/tundra/tundra.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://js.arcgis.com/3.11/esri/css/esri.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://js.arcgis.com/3.7/js/dojo/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../src/agsjs/css/agsjs.css" />

<script src="tabcontent.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">  
          var dojoConfig = { 
                paths: {
                       agsjs: '../src/agsjs' 
                    }
              };
      </script>
      <script src="http://js.arcgis.com/3.11/"></script>   
      <script>
       var map, toc, dynaLayer1, dynaLayer2, featLayer1;

        require(["dojo/_base/connect",
         "dojo/dom", "dojo/parser","dojo/on", "dojo/_base/Color",
         "esri/map",
         "esri/geometry/Extent", 
         "esri/layers/FeatureLayer",
         "esri/layers/ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer", 
         "esri/layers/ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer",
         "esri/symbols/SimpleFillSymbol",
         "esri/renderers/ClassBreaksRenderer",
         "agsjs/dijit/TOC", 
         "dijit/layout/BorderContainer", 
         "dijit/layout/ContentPane", 
         "dojo/fx", "dojo/domReady!"], function(connect,  dom, parser, on,Color,
         Map, Extent, FeatureLayer, ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer,   ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer, 
         SimpleFillSymbol,ClassBreaksRenderer,
         TOC){

                map = new Map("map", {
                basemap: "topo",
                center: [-85.75, 38.25],
                zoom: 13
              });

         });
  </script>
<style>
  #zoomin:hover,#zoomout:hover,#handtool:hover,#clip_map:hover
    {
    background-color:#fff;
    border-radius:5px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body class="tundra" style="padding:5px;height:100%;background-   image:url(background.jpg);">

  <div id="header" style="width:99%;height:40px;">
    <div id="tab_menu" style="width:29%;border:1px solid black;display:inline-block;height:95%;float:left;clear:both;">
        <ul class="tabs" data-persist="true">
            <li><a href="#layers">Layers</a></li>
            <li><a href="#legendDiv">Legend</a></li>
            <li><a href="#search_block">Search</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tool_options">Measurement</a></li>

        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="tools" style="width:70%;border:1px solid black;display:inline- block;height:100%;margin:0px;clear:both;"> 
    <div id="options" > 

  </div>


    </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div style="width:99%;height:950px">
    <div id="tabcontents" style="width:29%;border:1px solid black;display:inline-block;height:100%;float:left;clear:both">
            <div id="layers" style="padding:5px;"> <strong>Map Layers</strong><br/>
            <img id="loading" style="display:none" src="//dl.dropbox.com/u/2654618/loading_black.gif">
            <br>
            <div id="layerList" style="margin-left:5px;"></div>
            </div>
            <div id="legendDiv" style="padding:5px;"> </div>
            <div id="search_block" style="padding:5px;"><span> Search Map:</span>   
   <div id="search"></div> 
            <hr/>
            <h3> Custom Search </h3>
            <div id="search_critria" >

            </div>
            <div id="search_div">
            </div>
            </div>
            <div id="tool_options" style="margin-top:5px;margin-left:5px;">
                <div id="tool">
                </div>
                <div id="result"> 
                    <span style="cursor:pointer;" id="zoom_in" onclick="ZoomIn();">
                        <img style="height:25px" id="zoomin" src="images/zoomin.png"  /> 
                    </span> 
                    <span style="cursor:pointer;" id="zoom_out" onclick="ZoomOut()"> 
                        <img style="height:25px" id="zoomout" 
           src="images/zoomout.png" /> 
                    </span> 
                    <span style="cursor:pointer;" id="hand" onclick="HandTool()"> 
                        <img style="height:25px" id="handtool" 
           src="images/handTool.ico" /> 
                    </span>
                    <span style="cursor:pointer;" id="clip" onclick="Print()"> 
                        <img style="height:25px" id="clip_map" src="images/icon-print.png" /> 
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>

    <div id="map"  style="width:70%;border:1px solid black;display:inline-block;height:100%;margin:0px;clear:both;" > 
        <div style="height:200px;width:200px;overflow:hidden;position: absolute;bottom:60px; left: 83%;"> 
                <div id="overviewMapDiv" style="height:90%;"></div> 
        </div>
     </div>
    <div id="grid"></div>

  </div>
  </body>
   </html>
```

I have a folder named src, contains agsjs folder. when I run the page I got this error

GET http://js.arcgis.com/3.11/src/agsjs/dijit/TOC.js  init.js:40
Error: scriptError {src: "dojoLoader", info: Array[2], stack: (...), message: "scriptError"} init.js:41
src: dojoLoader init.js:41
info: ["http://js.arcgis.com/3.11/src/agsjs/dijit/TOC.js", Event]

Comment: Could you please use the Edit button above and let us know the URL to the TOC widget you're trying to configure? Eg is it [this one](https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=9b6280a6bfb0430f8d1ebc969276b109) or [this one](https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=9b6280a6bfb0430f8d1ebc969276b109)?

Comment: I edited the the question, the problem is that I'm not able to get the widget working on localhost on my computer.

Comment: Cool, thanks. That makes things a bit easier. Did you follow the steps in the [documentation](http://gmaps-utility-gis.googlecode.com/svn/tags/agsjs/latest/docs/toc/examples.html)? Can you share the relevant sections of your code, and/or some screenshots of what you're seeing?

Comment: It is working now, the problem was in this line  var dojoConfig = { 
                paths: {
                       agsjs: '../src/agsjs' 
                    }
              };
I changed it to this:
 var dojoConfig = { 
                    paths: {
                      //if you want to host on your own server, download and put in folders then use path like: 
                            agsjs: location.pathname.replace(/\/[^/]+$/, '') + '../src/agsjs' 
                        }
                  };
Thanks man :)

Comment: No worries, I did nothing! You should paste the above comment into an Answer instead, so you can then Accept the answer and close off this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found The problem, and it is working now, the problem was in this line

```
   var dojoConfig = { paths: 
         { agsjs: '../src/agsjs' } };
```

I changed it to this:

```
  var dojoConfig = { paths: { 
     agsjs: location.pathname.replace(/\/[^/]+$/, '') + '../src/agsjs' } };
```